# Insert product into an opportunity through the API

Tags: rest-api, soap-api

I am using the below code to insert a product into an opportunity.

```
   var AuthToken = authToken;
var JasonBody = "{\"Product2id\" : \"01t0b00000FmDlJ\",\"OpportunityId\" : \"0060b00000v8BUj\",\"Roll_call__c\" : 1.00,\"ESI_Quantity__c\" : 1,\"UnitPrice\" : 1.00,\"Quantity\" : 1}";               
    var DataEndpoint = "https://my--fit.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/OpportunityLineItem";
    var Action = "create";
    dynamic u = sfclient.Upsert(AuthToken, JasonBody, DataEndpoint, Action);
```

but I am getting the below error

```
{"[{\"message\":\"field integrity exception: PricebookEntryId (pricebook entry currency code does not match opportunity currency code)\",\"errorCode\":\"FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION\",\"fields\":[\"PricebookEntryId\"]}]"}
```

I can see the PricebookId and the CurrencyIsoCode linked to the opportunity when I query using the API so I am not sure what I am missing here.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `PricebookEntryId` instead of `Product2Id`. From the `OpportunityLineItem` [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_opportunitylineitem.htm) on `Product2Id` field:

> This is a read-only field
> available in API version 30.0 and later. Use the `PricebookEntryId`
> field instead, specifying the ID of the `PricebookEntry` record.

Comment: +1 Thanks. I forgot about that.

Comment: Getting this error {"[{\"message\":\"No such column 'PricebookEntryId ' on sobject of type OpportunityLineItem\",\"errorCode\":\"INVALID_FIELD\"}]"}